# Difference in floating point precision behavior between C and C#

Tags: c#, c, floating-point, precision, ieee-754

This is an academic question and so answers such as "just don't do that" miss the point.

I'm not trying to solve a problem - I'm trying to understand an observed behavior, namely a difference in how floating point math appears to function when comparing C and C#

### Assumption: float precision in C

It is my assumption that in C `floats` are implemented using a 23 bit mantissa and 8 bit exponent (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format)

For a given number, we can compute the smallest precision - the smallest value you can add to the number where purely structurally it cannot be stored anymore - by computing the value of the last bit of the mantissa.

If the floating point number is evaluated as:

```
[sign] * 1.[mantissa] * 2^[exponent]
```

Then because we have 23 bits in the mantissa the value of precision is `2^(exponent-23)`, where the exponent for a given number is:

```
floor(log2(number))
```

So the precision of a fairly large number like `10^9` is computed as follows:

```
exponent  = floor(log2(10^9))
          = 29

precision = 2^(exponent-23)
          = 2^(29-23)
          = 2^6
          = 64
```

This is the bare-metal, lowest absolutely theoretically possible value that can be added to `10^9` when stored as a float, because we're literally flipping the least significant bit of the mantissa:
[image]
[As visualized by the IEEE-754 Floating Point Converter](https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html)

I can also validate this with a quick C program ([run online](http://cpp.sh/33zc6)):

```c
#include <cstdio>

int main()
{  
  float number = 1e9f;          // exponent: 29, precision: 64
  printf("%'.0f\n", number);    // prints: 1000000000 
  
  number += 30;                 // 30 rounded to nearest multiple of 64 is 0 
  printf("%'.0f\n", number);    // prints: 1000000000 
  
  number += 40;                 // 40 rounded to nearest multiple of 64 is 64
  printf("%0'.0f\n", number);   // prints: 1000000064 
  
  return 0;
}
```

It is my assumption that the general 32 bit floating point format (1 bit sign, 8 bit exponent, 23 bit mantissa) is so universal that it's something intrinsic to modern CPUs, and so generally behavior would be the same across programming languages.

### Question: float precision in C#

So with that stated, when I try the same validation test in C# the value of the number does not change.

If I use a smaller value `10^8`, which would have an exponent of `26` and therefore a precision of `2^(26-23) = 8` given my above assumptions of how the bits of the floating point format represent the number internally, I notice the following behavior:

```cs
float number = 1e8f;                 // exponent: 26, precision: 8
Console.WriteLine($"{number,1:0}");  // prints: 100000000 

number += 30;                        // 30 rounded to multiple of 8 -should- be 32
Console.WriteLine($"{number,1:0}");  // prints: 100000000 

number += 40;                        // 40 rounded to multiple of 8 -should- be 40
Console.WriteLine($"{number,1:0}");  // prints: 100000100
```

And that... confuses me somewhat. Where did that 100 come from? That's not even a multiple of 2!

with a value of 1e8f C also behaves as expected and supports the precision being a value of '8': cpp.sh/6qesv

Looking at the [C# documentation for floating point values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/floating-point-numeric-types) nothing jumps out at me that would suggest that C# should handle float addition any differently here than C, and what I would expect given how floating point values are implemented.

The docs do mention that the approximate precision of floats is ~6-9 digits which is frustratingly vague.  I suppose that could be an answer: "you're dealing with digits past the guaranteed limit, it's undefined behavior" and while true, that is unsatisfying.

I would like to know, ideally broken down step by step, what actually happened in C#'s implementation there that makes it behave so differently than C here.

Comment: C# Float is 32-bit single-precision floating point type with 7 digit precision.

Comment: The result of your experiment depends very much on what floating point optimisations are in place.

Comment: Roman: So that partically explains it, but not completely. It makes sense why the result could only be an increase of 100, since the 7th digit in 10^8 is the 100s place.

However if we round to the nearest 100s, then the result should still have been 0 - 40 rounded to the nearest 100 is 0. how did it round from 40 to 100? I'd really appreciate a more detailed explanation.

Comment: Ah ok, under the hood it still stored more bits and so because I didn't reset the value after adding 30 and before adding 40, it actually was as if adding 70, which rounded to the nearest multiple of 8 is 72 and which rounded to the nearest 100 is indeed 100.

Comment: @Johannes This is a string formatting issue. If you change the C# format specifier from `{number,1:0}` to `{number:G9}` you'll see a more accurate representation of the underlying value.

Comment: Cheers! The confirms my suspicion: C# behaves -exactly- like C in this regard (how could it not, it only has so many bits), but how I was viewing the data had it rounded to the 7th digit.

Comment: So make this an answer and mark it, please.

Comment: "Where did that 100 come from? That's not even a multiple of 2!" --> I suspect you want "That's not even a _power_ of 2!" as 100 is a multiple of 2.

Answer (score 1):

Promoting my comment to an answer:

The problem here isn't floating point, it's differences in string formatting.  I'm not familiar with what, exactly, a format specified of "0" means or does (and can't seem to find it documented anywhere), but it's responsible for the unusual rounding you're seeing.

Using the format specifier of "G9" is [recommended](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings#the-general-g-format-specifier) for formatting a single precision float in such a way that it will round-trip correctly (meaning parsing the string back into a single precision float will reproduce the original value exactly).  If you change your code to use `{number:G9}` in the interpolated strings you should see the expected result.